# Can dynamodb table handle 1million requests per second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was reading up on Scaling in DynamoDB. I understand it reads in 4KB increments and I know that math (especially the ones taught in certifications).

So hypothetically if I have to design a system like TWITTER which can contain 1 million
requests per second (RPS) average size of each item about 20KB, can dynamodb support this?

A bit more:
20KB implies 20KB/4KB = 5 RCUs for standard read requests (not eventual consistent for the sake of the argument). How do I correlate this RCU figure of 5 to a million TPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DynamoDB supports some of the highest-scale sites on the internet. Amazon published some metrics about Prime Day load.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-prime-day-2020-powered-by-aws/

> Amazon DynamoDB powers multiple high-traffic Amazon properties and
> systems including Alexa, the Amazon.com sites, and all Amazon
> fulfillment centers. Over the course of the 66-hour Prime Day, these
> sources made 16.4 trillion calls to the DynamoDB API, peaking at 80.1
> million requests per second.

If you have a million RPS and each request is for 20 KB and you want them strongly consistent then you'd need to provision 5,000,000 RCU. If you're curious, you can calculate the cost based on us-east-1 pricing https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/ which is $0.00013 per RCU-hour provisioned, so that's $650 per hour.

Write capacity and data storage have separate pricing.

Comment: @huntercracker can dynamodb partitions support such hight  RCUs? I thought they are limited to 3000 RCUs and 1000 WCUs per partition. Also shouldn't your calculation be 2 million RCUs? ?  (5KB/4KB) rounded up =2 thus 2 *  million= 2 milion RCUs for Strongly consistent?

Comment: Sorry, typo, should've said 20 KB to match your expectations of 5 RCU for a strongly consistent read of 20 KB items. Fixed. As for the rest, one assumes you're not reading the same item a million times a second. If you are, use DAX as a cache in front. But as per twitter where load is across items, you can at scale get item calls to 3,000 RCU per second for any particular item, because the partitioning can when needed move things down to the item level to their own physical partition.

Comment: Maybe you could mention that at that level of consumption, nobody pays the retail rates ;-)

Comment: @Maurice could you elaborate that?

Comment: What @Maurice is saying is that if you are going to provision 5,000,000 RCU on a regular basis (not just for a one time event) it may be possible to negotiate some sort of volume discount.